# Git Password Cache

Tags: git, caching, github, passwords

git noob here. I am trying to set up password caching for GitHub by following [their documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git).

When I got to the step below I used 'which git' to see if my directory was the same as the example. My directory was /usr/bin/git . As the instructions said, I replaced the example path with my path.

```
(Example Path) $ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/local/git/bin

(My Path) $ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin/git
```

Unfortunately, there now seems to be a problem with Git. I can't run any Git commands. For example (git --help). If I try, it just returns a blank line. If I simply type Git into the terminal it returns

```
Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `which git` returns the path to the executable, not the path to the directory it's in.  `/usr/bin/git` is the binary, and you overwrote it.

Comment: Do i need to replace the git exec file in usr/bin/git ? If so, do you know how I would go about it ?

Comment: Hey Ed. I deleted the git file from usr/bin/git and everything seems to be working fine again. My only concern is do I need that git exec file in usr/bin/git ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've copied over your `git` binary with `git-credential-osxkeychain`. You probably wanted to do:

```
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin/
```

instead.

You'll need to re-install git, then copy the `git-credential-osxkeychain` binary to the right place.

When you say `which git` you get the name of the actual `git` program, not the folder.

Comment: Or, you can keep `git-credential-keychain` in `/usr/local/bin`, as long as `/usr/local/bin` is on your `$PATH`.