# get "git pull" to forget cached password

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

The first time I pulled a repo from github I used the following command

`git pull https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<repo>`

Then I would just type `git pull` and the repo updates automatically

In the last few days, I have been getting messages regarding removing the ability to use passwords to push or pull repos, and instead to generate a personal token

Now although I connected successfully using the new personal token, the old password I used for `git pull` is still cached and gives me the error `authentication failed`

How can I reset the cached `git pull` password?

On mac, the push command was reset successfully with `git config --global push.default simple` but on ubuntu the pull command is refusing to reset and is always cached to the old authentication unless I specifically put in the new username and password

Comment: have a look at your remote url with `git remote -v`, maybe you have to change it there

Comment: It's probably easiest to remove the remote and add it back using `git@github.com` instead of https.  You can probably edit the url, but blowing it away seems reasonable.  Or just create a new remote with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Most people come at this problem from the opposite direction: they'd like Git to *start* caching their password.  Hence the first several duplicates that I have found have the instructions reversed, as it were:

- [Is there a way to cache GitHub credentials for pushing commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/1256452)
- [Git Password Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751834/1256452)

The most relevant are these:

- [Remove cached password for Git on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50918607/1256452) (this is of course specific to Windows)
- [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/1256452)

The last one is the right place to look, but note that many answers are specific to Windows, including the accepted answer.  [This answer from irbanana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889429/1256452) is useful but I recommend that you read through *all* the answers, so as to learn how Git itself doesn't do anything about passwords.  Instead, it [fobs that job off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fob%20off) to some other program.  ("Fob off" here is meant somewhat [tongue-in-cheek](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tongue%20in%20cheek), since those other programs are far *better* at this than Git could possibly be.)